# iOS Swift WKWebView is not zooming

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I am working on an iOS application that has a web view to load inside it. I am using `WKWebView` but it is not zooming.

I set minimum and maximum scale of `webView's scrollView` but still doesn't work.

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.1
webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
```

How can I enable scaling of `WKWebView` ?

Answer (score 5):

works on Xcode 11, swift 4 , iOS 12,13  . Implement WebView navigationDelegate

```swift
    let isAllowZoom: Bool = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        webView.scrollView.bounces = false
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = false
        webView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        if isAllowZoom {
            let javascript = "var meta = document.createElement('meta');meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10.0, user-scalable=yes');document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);"
            webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascript, completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            let javascript = "var meta = document.createElement('meta');meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);"
            webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascript, completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

then try this :

```
        webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true               
        webView.scrollView.bounces = false                    
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = false   
        webView.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
//  Set the WKWebView scroll view delegate
        webView.scrollView.delegate = self
```

Conform your vc to UIScrollViewDelegate and add it's delegate method viewForZoomingInScrollView to return nil as follows :

```
 func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
```

Hope it helps to get your page adopt native behavior

Answer (score -3):

you have to set it's `scalesPageToFit` Property to `true` by adding :

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = true
```

Comment: webView.scalesPageToFit is available in UIWebView, but not in WKWebView